# Is there a tool to convert PHP from higher version to lower version?

Tags: php, ide, programming

Is there a converter to convert PHP code from a higher version (e.g. dropdown-select PHP 5.7) to a lower version (e.g. dropdown-select PHP 5.2)?

This would extremely useful  for compatibility with existing legacy systems. It **must** be able to convert PHP 5.3's [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) into the equivalent PHP 5.2's string-based versions using [`create_function`](//php.net/create_function). (Indeed that's the **only** feature I need actually.)

Of course, support for the additional features would be great too, e.g.:

- PHP 5.6's [argument unpacking](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php).
- PHP 5.4's "[permanent short echo tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use#comment22625737_200640)" `<?=` (in prior versions, this tag is only enabled if [`short_open_tag` etc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) are used). The app should provide an option to convert `<?=` into `<?php echo`.

**A standalone converter** (runnable at least on Windows) **would be sufficient**, though preferably an option to plugin-integrate with Notepad++ and possibly PHP Storm. (E.g. whenever I save a file e.g. `my_file.php.pre`, it would automatically do the conversions and output `my_file.php`.)

Comment: ([Meta discussion about this question](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1160/60).)

Comment: Must the tool be a PHP script/app as well? If so: which PHP versions must it be capable running under? If not: what OS must be supported – or must it be cross-platform? Though "Notepad++" indicates a Windows environment, please specify this explicitely – including conditions (e.g. "(fully) automated tool prefered to run on the Linux server; for manual run, preferably on the Windows workstation with, if possible, Notepad++ integration"). Not that I'd know an answer – but I'm pretty curious for it. Interesting question, +1 from me meanwhile in advance to your [edit] :)

Comment: @Pacerier is this any use? https://github.com/endel/php-code-downgrade - I'm not majorly familiar with PHP so not completely sure if it would help...

Comment: @Izzy, Yes I'm on Windows, have edited the question to include the specifics. The tool doesn't need to be coded in PHP.

Comment: @CalvT, Yes, something like that. However that only provides a 5.4 to 5.3 converter, so it doesn't have the capability to convert anonymous functions (introduced in 5.3)  to `create_function`.